# Compare Boolean Variables in one statement as long as array C++

Tags: c++, c++11, boolean-logic

Lets say I have an boolean array with 5 bool variables all being true

```
bool boo[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    boo[i] = true;
}
```

I want them all compared into one NAND logic gate at once because my problem is if I always compare two variables and compare the merged boolean to the i+1 boolean variable. This gives a wrong result.

```
    bool NANDGate(bool array[]){
    bool at;
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        if(i == 1){
            at = !(array[i-1] && array[i]);
        }else{
            at = !(at && array[i]);
        }
    }
    return at;
}
// result here is true even though it should be false
```

What I want is a right result when I put every variable from boo into a NAND gate so something maybe that looks like this:

```
bool func(bool array[]){
// some loop
result = !(array[0] && array[1] && array[2] && array[3] && array[4]);
return result;
}
// result here would be false
```

actually it doesn't have to look like that just maybe a solution that has a right result like the above would have.

EDIT: So many great solutions I thank you all

Comment: U wot? Could you write out the truth table please?

Comment: C++11 only or C++14 is OK? Or maybe C++17?

Comment: Understand that, `!(!(A && B) && C)` does not necessarily equal `!(A && B && C)` since by De Morgen's law, the former is equal to `(A && B) || (!C)` whilst the latter is equal to `!(A && B) || (!C)`.

Comment: I know but how do I write the code differently

Comment: Take the `&&` of all necessary params first then do the `!` at the end?

Comment: What do you mean by 'if I always compare two variables and compare the merged boolean to the i+1 boolean variable'?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

replace your definition by :

```
 bool NANDGate(bool array[]){
   bool at = array[0];
   for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
     at &&= array[i];
   }
   return !at;
 }
```

The not (`!`) must be made at the end to be compatible with `!(array[0] && array[1] && array[2] && array[3] && array[4]);`

And in your definition you also take into account some entries 2 times

But to do the && up to the end is useless, the best is just to do :

```
 bool NANDGate(bool array[]){
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     if (!array[i])
       return true;
   }
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: In your first example it seems more logical to set `at` to `true` and then `&&` everything since `true` is an identity operator for `&&`. Also note that under optimization, both versions (you proposed) are equivalent.

Comment: @Holt I save a turn in the loop initializing with the value of the first element. Do you think the compiler is able to optimize the first solution to do as the second ? In the doubt I prefer to do that myself, and finally if it does it is sad because the first is a poor programming and does not deserve to run as the second :-)

Comment: Saving one loop is useless, you should aim for readability, robustness, .... If you find the version initializing `at` with `array[0]` more readable, so be it, but doing so to gain one loop is useless. And yes, the first code is optimized slightly better than the second. And I don't see why the first one would be "poor programming".

Comment: Thank you of course the ! has to be at the end thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you accept a C++17 solution, you can make all `constexpr` using an helper function and template folding as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr bool NANDhelper (bool const (&a)[N],
                           std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return ! (a[Is] && ...); }

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr bool NANDgate (bool const (&a)[N])
 { return NANDhelper(a, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); }

int main ()
 {
   bool a[] { true, true, true, true, true };
   bool b[] { true, false, true, true, true };

   std::cout << NANDgate(a) << std::endl;
   std::cout << NANDgate(b) << std::endl;
 }
```

If you can't use C++17, but at least C++14, you can't use template folding but you can simulate it in an unused array initialization; something as follows

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr bool NANDhelper (bool const (&a)[N],
                           std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 {
   using unused = bool[];

   bool val { true };

   (void)unused { true, (val &= a[Is])... };

   return ! val; 
 }
```

Unfortunately `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` are available only starting from C++14 so, if you want something similar, you have to emulate them (and `NANDhelper()` can't be, in C++11, `constexpr`).

Comment: @bruno - yes: che C++14 version :-)

Comment: C++11 unfortunately

Comment: @max66 that has the merit to show the incredible possibilities we have in  modern C++, so I up vote héhé

Comment: @HaskellPlease - it's a pity :-(

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `std::all_of` with good readability as follows:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oFXGDx2ejCXDZJvf)

```
!std::all_of(std::begin(boo), std::begin(boo)+5, [](bool b){ return b; });
```

---

If you want to define the function `bool NANDGate(...)` with this STL function, then the following implementation well work for you:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5X1zRiaUCyJ9yra7)

```
bool NANDGate(const bool *arr, std::size_t n) 
{
    return !std::all_of(arr, arr+n, [](bool b){ return b; });
}
```

---

**Performance on GCC and Clang**

I tested the performance of the above function (labeled as `std::all_of`) and [the accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132855/compare-boolean-variables-in-one-statement-as-long-as-array-c/54132938#54132938) answer (labeled as `Naive`) by *Quick C++ Benchmark* with both gcc-8.2 and Clang-7.0 in C++14 and O3 optimization.
The result is as follows.
The horizontal line represents the sizes of each boolean arrays.
**In both compilers, `std::all_of` shows better performance than the naive implementation for the sizes greater than ~8:**

**GCC ([DEMO](http://quick-bench.com/nGIrwpYaHomKsfcoaXXo_H6IHp0)):**

[image]

**Clang ([DEMO](http://quick-bench.com/h8d7lBazxuh_eSd22IIo7B3Hcig)):**

[image]

Looking at the source code of GCC, the reason of this result would be rather clear.
The current GCC implementation of `std::all_of` can be seen in [*gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h*](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/440a7ea99590727841c3e6ba656e642401481314/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h) and following one:

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Predicate>
inline bool
all_of(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Predicate __pred)
{ 
    return __last == std::find_if_not(__first, __last, __pred);
}
```

where `std::find_if_not` is also implemented in the same file using a function `__find_if`. 
Note that there are two overload of `__find_if`.
The first one is the very simple following one:

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Predicate>
inline _InputIterator
__find_if(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
          _Predicate __pred, input_iterator_tag)
{
    while (__first != __last && !__pred(__first))
        ++__first;

    return __first;
}
```

**OTOH, the second one is a overload function for the random access iterators and optimized for them.**
The implementation is as follows. 
Since the distance of the random access iterators is quickly calculated with constant complexity O(1), this manual loop-unrolling effectively works.
In our current case, `boo` is a raw pointer that is a random access iterator.
Thus this optimized overload function is called.
This should be a reason why `std::all_of` shows better performance than the naive implementation for almost all sizes:

[**DEMO (RAI ver. is called)**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rm73NsSIz4D9Oj5j)

```
/// This is an overload used by find algos for the RAI case.
template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Predicate>
_RandomAccessIterator
__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
          _Predicate __pred, random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::difference_type __trip_count = (__last - __first) >> 2;

    for (; __trip_count > 0; --__trip_count)
    {
       if (__pred(__first))
           return __first;

       ++__first;

       if (__pred(__first))
           return __first;

       ++__first;

       if (__pred(__first))
           return __first;

       ++__first;

       if (__pred(__first))
           return __first;

       ++__first;
    }

    switch (__last - __first)
    {
    case 3:
      if (__pred(__first))
          return __first;

      ++__first;
    case 2:
      if (__pred(__first))
          return __first;

      ++__first;
    case 1:
      if (__pred(__first))
          return __first;

      ++__first;
    case 0:
    default:
      return __last;
    }
}
```

Although I don't know the details of the Clang implementations, that seems also to be optimized from the above plot.
In addition, with the same reason, functions proposed by @0x0x5453 and @TobySpeight would also show better performance at least in these compilers.

Comment: This does not compile within OP's proposed function. `std::begin` is not defined for `bool*` or any `T*`, and if you plan on using `T (&)[5]`, you can replace `std::begin(foo) + 5` by `std::end(foo)`. Furthermore, this produce much less efficient code than other proposed solutions with optimization enabled.

Comment: @Holt thx and you are right! If OP really needs a function with the interface `bool NANDGate(bool array[])`, this does not successfully compile.

Comment: @Holt BTW, why can you say that "*this produce much less efficient code*"? Is that because of C++ standard only says *Complexity: At most last - first applications of the predicate.* in [alg.all_of] ?

Comment: I compared the generated assembly of both versions.

Comment: `gcc` and `clang` produce [similar outputs](https://godbolt.org/z/RbcZO3).

Comment: thx, but why do you think that these assembly of `nand2` slower than the one of `nand1`?

Comment: @Holt Hi, I tried to validate statement about which answer is more efficient but QuickBench showed me different results. Can you help me and point me what am I doing wrong in this benchmarks? [Clang](http://quick-bench.com/Vsv0SPwIO8uL2ThYluE6UN3kjy8) and [GCC](http://quick-bench.com/cQdwXb0Da9u_LQc9qEYpAERbf2A). Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The following should do it:

```
bool NANDGate(bool array[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (!array [i])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution using modern C++:

```
template <class CONTAINER>
bool NANDGate(const CONTAINER& container) {
    auto is_false = [](const auto& item) { return !(bool)item; };
    return std::any_of(std::begin(container), std::end(container), is_false);
}
```

Comment: Consider using existing `std::logical_not<bool>()` functor rather than defining equivalent lambda.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is C++, we don't need to write a loop; we can use `std::any_of` instead.

We need our NAND gate to return `true` if any input is false:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

bool NANDGate(const bool array[])
{
    return std::any_of(array, array+5, std::logical_not<bool>());
}

int main()
{
    const bool boo[10] = { true, true, true, true, true };

    return NANDGate(boo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ has `std::bitset` particularly for cases like this. A clean solution with C++11:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>


const unsigned gateSize = 5;


int main ()
{
    std::bitset<gateSize> booBits;

    //Set all bits to true by this simple function call...
    booBits.set();

    //... or some loop
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < gateSize; ++i)
        booBits[i] = 1;

    std::cout << !booBits.all() << std::endl; //This is your NANDgate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I use `std::bitset` many will frown, but with it  there'd be no need for a function:

```
std::bitset<10> boo;
//...
bool boo_nand1= !boo.all();
bool boo_nan2=(~boo).any();
```